# In Unix, re-direction from sed into file causes emptying of file.

Tags: bash, unix, redirect, sed

I was trying to replace all instances of "unix"(ignore cases) to "oracle". So, I cat the "testfile2" and pipe and after sed I redirected back to the same file "testfile2". But the file becomes empty. Can someone please help debug.

```
bash-3.2$ cat testfile2
uniX
udfi
unix
UNix
UNIX
Unix
ockcl
cunci

bash-3.2$ cat testfile2 |tr [A-Z] [a-z] |sed 's/unix/oracle/g' > testfile2
bash-3.2$ cat testfile2
bash-3.2$
```

I was able to get a workaround using a tee as follows, but couldn't figure why redirection didn't work.

```
bash-3.2$ cat testfile2 |tr [A-Z] [a-z] |sed 's/unix/oracle/g' |tee  testfile2
oracle
udfi
oracle
oracle
oracle
oracle
ockcl
cunci

bash-3.2$ cat testfile2
oracle
udfi
oracle
oracle
oracle
oracle
ockcl
cunci
```

*I'm using bash version 3.2.57(1)-release (solaris2.10)*

Answer (score 3):

`cat testfile2 |tr [A-Z] [a-z] |sed 's/unix/oracle/g' > testfile2`

When the shell sees `> testfile2` it truncates the file to zero bytes - this is done before anything else.  It is not done "after sed" but before it!  The fact that you put the redirection on the right is irrelevant (most people do that, but actually you can put it almost anywhere).

Redirect to a different filename (e.g. `testfile2.tmp`) then use `mv` to rename it after your command runs successfully.

Edit:

As @tripleee points out, `[A-Z] [a-z]` is wrong.  `tr` does not use regular expression or glob constructs (wildcards), the square brackets would mean to translate square brackets, if they were inside quotes.

But they are not inside quotes, so the `[A-Z] [a-z]` will be interpreted by *the shell* and will be substituted for filenames.  However that will only happen if you have single character filenames in the current directory - unlikely but possible. `tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'` is correct.

Comment: Of course, [the `cat` is completely superfluous](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html)

Comment: Also, the brackets are not useful with `tr` and if you don't quote them properly, they could be expanded as wildcards by the shell.  You mean `tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'` plain and simple (where the quoting is now less crucial, but included for good taste).

Comment: @trpleee Normally I would agree with the `cat``, but `tr` does not take a filename as an argument - it is not a filter program.  There are other ways to avoid the `cat`, but none of that is relevant to the question.

Comment: Proliferating the useless `cat` antipattern is a disservice to the community. It's not a big deal here but rewriting it as `tr A-Z a-z <testfile2` is not a big deal either, and might actually make a difference if somebody puts this in the innermost loop in a busy program.

Comment: @tripleee:  point taken, I agree.